# Как узнать, на каком сервере выполняется мой PHP скрипт?

Tags: php

Мой скрип меняет свою работу в зависимости о того, на каком сайте расположен.
Если он выполняется на сайте mydomain.com, то я хочу, чтобы в переменной `$q` у меня было 'mydomain.com'. А если на localhost, то, соответственно, 'localhost'.
Спасибо!

Comment: см. [SERVER_NAME](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Выяснить название текущего хоста можно из переменной окружения `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

```
$q = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
switch($q) {
  case 'mydomain.com' :
    // Продакшен среда
    break;
  default :
    // Локальная разработка
}
```

Можно установить собственную переменную окружения, если стандартная переменная окружения `SERVER_NAME` по каким-то причинам не подходит. Например, ваш движок используется на нескольких хостах и нельзя размещать имя хоста непосредственно в коде. В этом случае вы можете определить переменные окружения с нейтральными значениями, не зависящими от доменного имени (dev, prod, staging, test и т.п.) Для этого на уровне виртуального хоста или location-секции, отвечающий за обработку php-файлов следует прописать директиву, устанавливающую переменную окружения

**nginx**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_param APP_HOST prod; 
    ...
}
```

**apache**

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
   ...
   SetEnv APP_HOST prod
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

В результате этого в PHP-скрипте будет доступна переменная окружения `APP_HOST`, получить доступ к котором можно через `$_SERVER['APP_HOST']` (значение 'prod').